# extract key-value pairs from a python dictionary, according to the value of a specific key

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary or a dictionary of list, d1 and d2 as below.

```
d1 = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'score':1},{'A':11, 'B':22, 'score':2},{'A':111, 'B':2222, 'score':3}]
d2 = {'A':[1,11,111], 'B':[2,22,222], 'score':[1,2,3]}
```

I need to 'filter' the dictionary by value of a key. For example, I need the value of 'A' and 'B' , where score is highest. What I want is:

```
{'A':111, 'B':2222}
```

One way I can do is to convert the dictionary list to pandas dataframe, filter rows and convert back to dictionary. But that is really inefficient....

Thanks a lot for advice in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
d1 = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'score':1}, {'A':11, 'B':22, 'score':2},{'A':111, 'B':2222, 'score':3}]
d2 = {'A':[1,11,111], 'B':[2,22,222], 'score':[1,2,3]}

a = []
for i in d1:
    a.append(i['score'])

b = max(a)

for i in d1:
    if i['score'] == b:
        c = i
        del c['score']

print(c)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 sent_find.py 
> {'A': 111, 'B': 2222}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Transform d1 to d2 style, then

`idx=d2['score'].index(max(d2['score']))`

`_new = {'A':d2['A'][idx], 'B': d2['B'][idx]}`